# Very specific chrome bug with rem and vw calculation

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, viewport-units

I'm using `rem`, calculated from `vw`, like this:

```
html {
    font-size: 1px;
    font-size: #{100/($design-width+$scrollbar-width)}vw;
    font-size: calc(100vw / #{$design-width+$scrollbar-width});
}
```

It seems to work on all modern browsers, so i'm using this across all my projects. Recently i've received this [video](https://youtu.be/4kU9VpAKil8), demonstrating strange behavour of my layout.

Unfortunately, i'm unable to test anything on this browser, I only know what it's google chrome 54, firefox on same pc works well, disabling extensions and starting incognito session not helping.

As I see from this video, rem's are calculating right only when it's applied to `font-size` property. Width/height, margin/padding, borders and so on works wrong.

Sites shown in video are aviable [here](http://uver-pro.ru/) and [here](http://xn--24-jlc0d.xn--p1ai/). Please provide full info about your brovser if you experiencing same problem as in video. I've tested on all availbale devices, but i can't reproduce the error.

**UPD:**
Here is [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7db4enkq/) with MCVE, and screenshots of how it looks on my pc and on pc from video.

[image: My PC][image: PC from video]

Comment: Can you create an [mcve] that demonstrates the issue? Debugging won't be easy with only a video for a reference.

Comment: @MrLister If I could create MCVE for this, my question would be unnecessary. I can create a minimal example, what *may* behave as in video on browser from video, but since I can't test it, this is pointless.